# Mysql error values missing

Tags: mysql

There are invalid values for the `qa_contact` column in the bugs
table. (These values do not exist in the `profiles` table, in the `userid`
column.)

Below is the error:

> ERROR: There are invalid values for the qa_contact column in the bugs
>   table. (These values do not exist in the profiles table, in the userid
>   column.) Before continuing with checksetup, you will need to fix these
>   values, either by deleting these rows from the database, or changing
>   the values of qa_contact in bugs to point to valid values in
>   profiles.userid. The bad values from the bugs.qa_contact column are: 4,
>   5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30,
>   32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 40, 41, 45, 46, 47, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 61,
>   62, 63, 68, 70, 73, 74, 85, 90, 91, 92, 95, 101, 102, 103, 112, 122,
>   124, 126, 129, 135, 142, 156, 157, 161, 166, 172, 175, 178, 207, 208,
>   209, 212, 215, 216, 221, 222, 223, 224, 226, 231, 237, 238, 239, 240,
>   242, 245, 248, 250, 251, 253, 254, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 267,
>   270, 273, 276, 278, 279

Please guide me how to add missing values

Comment: the error message tells you exactly what to do though

Answer (score 0):

You Can do for existing record

```
DELETE bugs WHERE bugs.qa_contact NOT IN
(4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 40, 41, 45, 46, 47, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 58, 61, 62, 63, 68, 70, 73, 74, 85, 90, 91, 92, 95, 101, 102, 103, 112, 122, 124, 126, 129, 135, 142, 156, 157, 161, 166, 172, 175, 178, 207, 208, 209, 212, 215, 216, 221, 222, 223, 224, 226, 231, 237, 238, 239, 240, 242, 245, 248, 250, 251, 253, 254, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 267, 270, 273, 276, 278, 279);
```

You should check for bug records for validity

```
SELECT * from profiles p INNER JOIN bugs b ON p.userid = b.qa_contact WHERE b.qa_contact = '253'
```

then if no records returned then  you should delete that records from bugs table

```
DELETE FROM bugs WHERE qa_contact = '253'
```

Or

update table , one of the table according to your missing value.